# node.js post causes error

Tags: node.js, express

I am running this app. https://github.com/azat-co/practicalnode 
chapter 5- blog-express app.

the only change is twitter consumer key and secret I made in app.js file

I can run this app and sign-in with twitter.
But when I try to post an article it causes error.

```
Connect
400 Error: request size did not match content length

    at makeError (/home/myname/Documents/nodejs/practicalnode/ch7/blog-express/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:136:15)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/myname/Documents/nodejs/practicalnode/ch7/blog-express/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:938:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

What should I check?what could be wrong.
thanks

Comment: Which app? The URL you linked to just shows a bunch code samples organized by chapter of a programming book.

Comment: @mscdex blog-express

Comment: There are 3 chapters that have a `blog-express` subdirectory.